# Saving/loading layout preferences

Tags: android

My app has around 25 items that users can change attributes on. They can show/hide them, set the text, change the color, etc. And they can save multiple sets of these settings.

I'm trying to come up with the best way to handle this. I could use sharedpreferences and store the value of each attribute for each of the ~25 items and prefix them with the name of the saved set of settings. Then regardless of if any changes were made, load the values for everything on start/selection of a new set and save all values on close/save of new set.

I'm not sure that's the best way though. Anyone have ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) is very powerful for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your java objects that implements Serializable interface. Then you can save this serialized string to an internal file. Afterwards you can get these objects by deserializing objects. By using this method your data will be private and nobody will see your data, this is not the case when you use sharedpreferences. This method is very flexible so that you can save all objects that implements Serializable interface. I am using this method to save my preferences.